# how to export .pfx file from azure vm to azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Please help:

I am trying to Configure secure LDAP for an Azure AD Domain Services managed domain. I have followed the below link , created a pfx certificate on a azure vm. However the to enable secure LDAP for the managed domain we have to upload the pfx file in azure portal ( according to task 3 ) from below link.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap-enable-ldaps

I am not sure as to how would to export the pfx file from azure vm to azure portal. I did trying exporting the file using winscp but after uploading it failed with incorrect file error

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the PFX file to locally and browse the PFX file with LDAP certificate from your local environment. You cannot export the PFX file from Azure VM to Azure Portal.